# Getting video height and width via Java

Tags: java, video, width

Is there a general way to get the height and width of a video file in Java.
I receive/own video files in formats such as .mov, .avi, .mpg, mp4, 3gp, and m4v and wish to display them systematically using java generated web pages. Currently, I am generating HTML 5 code where height and width are needed. Posts so far suggest using ASP.net or XUGGLER but these may be overkill for what I want to do.  Any suggestions for getting these values?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an easy way to extract video size but I did find an easy workaround. 
First I converted all my valued videos to MPEG4. It took several tries of various converters and finally I found one that worked consistently but on OS X:
WinX HD Video Converter for Mac

(Space savings are huge.)
Next, on a hunch I tried mapping all my videos to 70% of my screen size and results are very satisfactory.  Here is a sample display page for a video.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><BODY><small>
</small><video width="70%" height="70%" autoplay>
<source src="A1_Howard_Show2__.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video format .mp4!
</video></body></html>
```

Comment: IF without conversion of video:  This will work but is limited to supporting only a few video codecs. Like it wont play video having codec "mp4v" type. Try it and you'll get 0 as height width of video